# Emulate Samsung Galaxy Apollo

Tags: emulation, dpi, samsung-mobile, heap-size

I want to test Samsung Galaxy Apollo on Android SDK emulator. What DPI and heap size I must use?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate the DPI with this site I found on the net: [calculate dpi](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html). The Galaxy Apollo has a 3.2 inch display with 240x400 display resolution (I found on the official samsung website).

edit: [the official samsung galaxy apollo site](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I5800DKAXEU-spec)

Comment: Thanks! But I still need to know VM heap size.

Comment: Maybe you can download a prefabricated apollo emulator for eclipse. I thought they exist. Or you can use a real Samsung Galaxy smartphone to check your app.